# Generate RAML file for existing API in Java

Tags: java, rest, mulesoft, raml

I am new to RAML and I am looking for a tool or any way by which I can create the RAML file by passing few details. It will take a lot of time if I try to write RAML files for existing API manually.

Below is the desired RAML file format.

```
%RAML 1.0
baseUri: https://api.test.com/abc
title: Test
version: v1

traits:
     id-required:
      headers:
       id:
        type: string
       secret:
        type: string

/test/:
  description:Test  API
  post:
    is: [id-required]
    description: Test  
    body: 
      application/json:
        example: !include examples/TestRequest.json
        type: !include schemas/TestRequestSchema.json
    responses: 
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: !include examples/TestResponse.json
            type: !include schemas/TestResponseSchema.json
      400:
        body: 
          application/json:
            example: !include examples/TestErrorResponse.json
            type: !include schemas/TestResponseSchema.json
```

Thanks,
Rachana

Comment: I'm sorry, the question is not clear. Why do you want to create a RAML if you already have it? Please focus the question on what you are trying to achieve. For example, what do you need the RAML for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DocDog.
From there it creates RAML from the existing source code.
If it is SpringBoot you can run it easily with `-lang=spring`. If it is plain JAVA you can add comments to your code (see readme.md or examples), so DogDoc can understand.

May it helps you:
https://github.com/skalski/docdog